# How to create MSI from Jenkins Server when installshield is installed on a remote machine

Tags: c#, jenkins, continuous-integration, installshield

I have my CI setup on Jenkins.There is another machine where Installshield is configured.I need my final build on CI to call the msi template from remote machine(where installshield is present) and create MSI from it.

Answer (score 1):

On the machine where Jenkins is installed you'll need to install the [ISCmdBld.exe](https://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield24helplib/helplibrary/ISCmdBldParam.htm) which is the build executable for InstallShield. Then "get" your ism and stage files on that machine and build there.

Answer (score 0):

You may use PsExec tool for executing the msi template using installshield remotely. Otherwise, you may install Jenkins client on the machine where InstallShield is installed and execute the job on the same agent.